# how to concatenate two digits as string by jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to convert dd-mm-yyyy to yyyymmdd and put it to another input field of a html form. I used following jquery code for this purpose:

```
var date = $(this).val();
  var d=new Date(date.split("-").reverse().join("-"));
  var dd=d.getDate();
  var mm=d.getMonth()+1;
  var yy=d.getFullYear();
  $('#payid').val(mm+dd+yy);
```

Let a date is `19-09-2016`. I want it to be converted to `20160919`. But it is returning 2044. So, it is adding 19, 09 & 2016. How can I concanate instead of summing the dd, mm & yyyy?

Comment: All you need is: `date.split("-").reverse().join("")`. There is no need to create a date object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to build the string manually at all, you can just split the string, reverse it and re-join it without the `-` separator:

```
date.split("-").reverse().join('');
```

```js
var date = '19-09-2016'; // $(this).val();
var d = date.split("-").reverse().join('')
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. Worked well.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Use `toString()` function

```
var date = $(this).val();
  var d=new Date(date.split("-").reverse().join("-"));
  var dd=d.getDate();
  var mm=d.getMonth()+1;
  var yy=d.getFullYear();
  $('#payid').val(mm.toString()+dd.toString()+yy.toString();
```

Also

```
date.split("-").reverse().join("")
```

will work. It saves your from the complications.

Answer (score 0):

`mm+""+dd+""+yy` should work fine